# "Crumbling sidewalk" vs. "crumbled sidewalk"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

Which one is correct?

I was walking on **crumbling** or **crumbled** sidewalk.

I think "crumbled" is more correct, because the side walk *crumbled by people or by cars.

It can make no sense by saying "sidewalk is crumpling"

What do you say about this?

Comment: Typically we use `crumbling` because it is an ongoing process - even if the sidewalk is already pretty bad, it's still wearing down day by day.  `Crumbled` would really imply that the sidewalk's disrepair is no longer continuing to worsen - perhaps because it completely fell apart to the point it can no longer be called a sidewalk at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both can be correct.

The usual way to express this idea is *crumbling sidewalk*.  It is in a state of falling apart.  But you could say "The sidewalk was completely crumbled" or "The sidewalk had completely crumbled".

**To crumble** is both transitive and intransitive.

You can crumble a cookie.  <sup>transitive</sup>

A brick wall can crumble with many years of freeze and thaw, if there are small cracks in the mortar which allow water to enter. <sup>intransitive</sup>